# Loop through parent array in session variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, session-variables

**In testing code to learn how arrays work when stored to session variables I have made the following stored arrays:**

```
$id=17; //product #17
$_SESSION['cart']['items'][$id]=array(
   'quantity'=>1,
   'SKUNumber'=>'GL335-a',
   'Name'=>'Widget',
   'UnitPrice'=>14.95
);
$id=25; 
$_SESSION['cart']['items'][$id]=array(
   'quantity'=>3,
   'SKUNumber'=>'GL398-c',
   'Name'=>'Mega-Widget',
   'UnitPrice'=>34.95
);
$id=19;
$_SESSION['cart']['items'][$id]=array(
   'quantity'=>1,
   'SKUNumber'=>'GL335-a',
   'Name'=>'Widget',
   'UnitPrice'=>14.95
);
```

**I am confused on how to loop through the Key > Values at the ITEM level:**

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart']['items'][25] as $key=>$value) // echo/loop all stored vaules in the item 25 array in session cart
    {
    // and print out the values
    echo $key." | ".$value."<br />";
    }
```

**correctly produces 1 occurrence of the array stored in item 25:**

- quantity | 3
- SKUNumber | GL398-c
- Name | Mega-Widgets
- UnitPrice | 34.95

**But, when i remove the [25] from the code, i get: 17 | Array, 25 | Array, 13 | Array
and a warning: "Notice: Array to string conversion in..."**

**What I want to produce is:**

quantity: 1 | SKUNumber: GL335-a |Name: Widget |UnitPrice: 14.95

quantity: 3 | SKUNumber: GL398-c |Name: Mega-Widget |UnitPrice: 34.95

quantity: 1 | SKUNumber: GL378-b |Name: Super Widget |UnitPrice: 29.95

**I'm obviously looping through the result set in a wrong way but not sure the correct way to loop through it to get the result I'm looking for. Thanks for any help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    foreach($_SESSION['cart']['items'] as $arr)
    {
        echo "quantity: $arr['quantity'] | SKUNumber: $arr['SKUNumber']: GL378-b | Name: $arr['Name'] | UnitPrice: $arr['UnitPrice']";
    }
```

About `Notice: Array to string conversion in`, you're going to print out `$value` which is an array not a string so that's why you get that notice.

You should iterate over your array with another `foreach` loop or you can go with the my snippet.

Comment: Thank you, I had to echo it with joins to pass syntaxt check but it did work: `foreach($_SESSION['cart']['items'] as $arr)
    {
        echo "quantity: ".$arr['quantity']." | SKUNumber: ".$arr['SKUNumber']." | Name: ".$arr['Name']." | UnitPrice: ".$arr['UnitPrice']."<br>";
    }
`

Comment: this wont work simply because the value assigned to $arr in your foreach is now the id pointing to another array... `[17]=>array(...),[25]=>array(...),[19]=>array(...)`. Your code would echo "quantity:| SKUNumber: | Name:| UnitPrice: "

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart']['items'] as $id=>$arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.":" .$value." | ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

OR

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart']['items'] as $id=>$arr) {
    echo "quantity: $arr['quantity'] | SKUNumber: $arr['SKUNumber'] | Name: $arr['Name'] | UnitPrice: $arr['UnitPrice'] <br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to serialize an Array by echoing the value, thats why you get the warning and the unexpected result. Try handling the $value as an array instead of just echoing it. Or looping inside the $value

Comment: I assume by looping inside the value that you mean to setup a loop inside the existing loop, if that's the case then i have never tried that before but i will give it a shot. I knew why the notice was generating, just didn't know how to overcome it properly. Thanks